# I want to know what is Facebook's algorithms language

Tags: facebook

Which language is facebook using for their friend recommending system??

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]! This is a  programmers Q&A site.  [so] is not Facebook customer support - we are regular users just like you!  Your question needs to be directed to Facebook themselves.  Sad thing is - there is no way to get in contact with them :(  Please read over the [faq] to learn what types of questions are allowed here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's anything special. Probably PHP compiled with their [Hip-Hop](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2010/02/02/hiphop-for-php--move-fast/) compiler. Then when you visit Facebook they show you a number of their lastet computations and start a new background task to generate fresh ones.